# Multiple sort Array Object according to {liked :true} , distance and then by avg_rating

Tags: javascript, node.js, sorting

I have an array Object as following

```
arr = [ {distance:4, avg_rating: 5}, 
        {distance: 6, avg_rating: 4}, 
        {distance: 7, avg_rating: 2, liked: true}, 
        {distance: 6, avg_rating: 4 , liked: true}, 
        {distance: 6, avg_rating: 3 , liked: true},
        {distance: 4, avg_rating: 3}]
```

I wish to get First of all {liked: true} and then it would be sorted by distance in ascending order and if distance is same then it would be sorted according to avg_rating.

I have used sort method of javascript which is not working.

```
arr.sort(function(a, b){                                     
      if (b.liked)  return  1;
      if(!b.liked) return -1;
      if (a.distance < b.distance) return 1;
      if (a.distance > b.distance) return -1;
      if (a.avg_rating < b.avg_rating) return -1;
      if (a.avg_rating > b.avg_rating) return 1;
 })
```

I expect the result would be

```
arr = [{distance: 6, avg_rating: 4 , liked: true},
       {distance: 6, avg_rating: 3 , liked: true}
       {distance: 7, avg_rating: 2, liked: true},
       {distance: 4, avg_rating: 5},
       {distance: 4, avg_rating: 3},
       {distance: 6, avg_rating: 4}]
```

So that, First all { liked : true } are on top and sorted by distance in ascending order (i.e. all nearby are on top of array) and then if distance is same then sort by avg_rating in descending order (i.e. all same distance values are again sorted by avg_rating )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could chain all condition and get the wanted order by getting the delta of each item.

For the first pair take a [logical NOT `!`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_NOT) to get a boolean value for subtraction.

The other ones are taken in the order of sorting, `a - b` (asc) and `b - a` (desc).

```js
var array = [{ distance: 4, avg_rating: 5 }, { distance: 6, avg_rating: 4 }, { distance: 7, avg_rating: 2, liked: true }, { distance: 6, avg_rating: 4, liked: true }, { distance: 6, avg_rating: 3, liked: true }, { distance: 4, avg_rating: 3 }];

array.sort((a, b) =>
    !a.liked - !b.liked ||
     a.distance - b.distance ||
     b.avg_rating - a.avg_rating
);

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```